# How to read a text file while developing an ios app using xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, text

I'm now developing an iOS app using xcode(Swift). I want to import the data which is stored in a text file, and show the words from the text file on the screen. How can I import an existing text file into the project? Should I install anything? How can I read the text file and store the words in an array?

Comment: That question seems to be about the APIs for reading a text file.  This question seems to be about how to use Xcode to make the text file available to the iOS app in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a file easily in iOS. Follow these steps:

**Step 1: Add a File into project**

[image]

**Step 2: Reading a file**

**EDIT**

Swift:

```
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "File", ofType: "txt");
    let URL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath!)

    do {
        let string = try String.init(contentsOf: URL)

        // use string here
        print("read: " + string)
    } catch  {
        print(error);
    }
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the OP is clearly stating the language as Swift. Your answer is so suggestive, but never can be a _good answer_ when Swift code is given.

Comment: @OOPer, I forgot to notice. Thank you so much. I updated answer.